# .each returning entire array after iterating through each element

Tags: ruby, arrays, function, view

I have a function in ruby

```
def words
    ret =""

    res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|http.request(req)}

    res.body.each_line do |line|
        words = line.split("\"")
        ret << words[1] << " "
    end

    return ret
end
```

say ret returns "Bill Dan Mike Sarah".

in my view I am doing

```
<%= @class.words.split(" ").each do |name| %>
        <p><%= name %></p>
<% end %>
```

Instead of just displaying each name on a line, it does

> Bill
>
> Dan
>
> Mike
>
> Sarah
>
> ["Bill", "Dan", "Mike", "Sarah"] #this  shouldn't be printed

What is causing it to display the entire array there at the end? How do I prevent this?

Comment: A Rails tag, please.

Comment: Just a couple of hours ago, I wanted to write a snarky comment about how tired I am of this exact same question popping up again and again every couple of hours, but then I thought "every couple of hours" is a little harsh … and what do you know, just 9 hours later, someone actually *does* ask it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove an extra `=` from first line in [`each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-each):

```
<% @class.words.split(" ").each do |name| %>
  <p><%= name %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: wow I feel dumb...thank you sigh. can't believe I couldn't figure that out after staring at this for 30 minutes